# Can Fortran 95 compiler compile Fortran 77 code?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77, fortran95

Currently I'm compiling fortran95 source codes on mac using gfortran 6.1. I was wondering if I can run FORTRAN 77 source codes using the same. If not, any suggestions?

Comment: With a few exceptions, valid Fortran 77 programs are valid Fortran 95 programs.  Just very badly written Fortran 95 programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not mention what error you encountered during the compilation process. See [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html). Specifically:

```
    -std=*std*
```

where *std* may be one of ‘f95’, ‘f2003’, ‘f2008’, ‘gnu’, or ‘legacy’. The

> Default value for std is ‘gnu’. From the same page: 
>   The ‘legacy’ value is equivalent but without the warnings for obsolete extensions, and may be useful for old non-standard programs. The ‘f95’, ‘f2003’ and ‘f2008’ values specify strict conformance to the Fortran 95, Fortran 2003 and Fortran 2008 standards, respectively; errors are given for all extensions beyond the relevant language standard, and warnings are given for the Fortran 77 features that are permitted but obsolescent in later standards.

For example, if you have a file `old_fortran.f77` to compile, you could do:

```
   gfortran -std=legacy old_fortran.f77 -o a.out
```

where `-o a.out` gives you the executable `a.out`. I have used an older version of this compiler successfully without using this option. You may get some warnings though. First try:

```
   gfortran old_fortran.f77 -o a.out
```

EDIT: After looking at comments below by OP, it looks like  a different issue may be involved. It might be that either your installation is faulty (which is possible) or your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is messed up. I think your linker (ld) in your path is 32bit and the object file that was created by your compiler might have been 64 bit. Just a hunch. Can you post the output of

```
  which ld
```

suppose that returns: /path/to/ld. Then take that output and do

```
  file /path/to/ld
```

Can you post the output of both commands as comment?

Comment: Thanks. I'm very new to fortran programming, so don't know much technical words now. Will wait for more details.

Comment: I tried both ways, got same error.  ld: warning: ignoring file epi.f77, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): epi.f77
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: try creating a small "Hello World" program and compile it. If it succeeds then you have a problem elsewhere. Can you tell us how you are compiling epi.F77? what is the output of "file epi.F77"

Comment: I tried "hello world" and got the following error.
ld: warning: ignoring file hello.f77, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x20 0x70 0x72 0x6F 0x67 0x72 0x61 0x6D 0x20 0x6D 0x61 0x69 0x6E 0x0A 0x0A 0x63 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): hello.f77
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Vineetha This should be in the question. But probably you should ask a new question as this question has an answer already.

Comment: @Jagte I think the edit doesn't have a place in this answer, the original question does not mention anything like that. Definitely do not ask new questions from the author in the question, only in comments.

Comment: @Vladimir, was just checking out on of your work on Stackoverflow documentation. You are making great contribution to this community. Anyway, you are right about this post.

Answer (score 2):

Its working if I use

> gfortran old_fortran.f -o a.out

Comment: So what did you do in the first place that didnt work? a.out is the default so you dont even need that.

Comment: @agentp  I wa using old_fortran.f77 as suggested  in the previous answer.

Comment: @Vineetha `.f77` is not used by any convention, AFAIK. Usual Fortran77 extensions are indeed `.f`, `.for` or `.F`, if the code needs to be processed by C preprocessor.